# Installing AppFabric 1.1 on Windows Server 2012 Giving Error

Tags: installation, appfabric, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install `AppFabric 1.1` on my `Windows Server 2012` but it is not installing. it gives error like.

```
AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code:1603
```

The log file that has been created is as follows.

```
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  ===== Logging started: 2013-03-05 18:06:29+05:30 =====
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  File:             c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\setup.exe
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  InternalName:     Setup.exe
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  FileVersion:      1.1.2106.32
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  FileDescription:  Setup.exe
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Product:          Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server AppFabric
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  ProductVersion:   1.1.2106.32
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Debug:            False
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Patched:          False
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  PreRelease:       False
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  PrivateBuild:     False
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  SpecialBuild:     False
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Language:         Language Neutral
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  OS Name:                   Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate Datacenter
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  OS Edition:                ServerDatacenter
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  OSVersion:                 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.8400.0
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  CurrentCulture:            en-US
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Processor Architecture:    AMD64
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Event Registration Source :    AppFabric_Setup
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1.0 Upgrade module.
2013-03-05 18:06:29, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed.
2013-03-05 18:06:38, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1 Upgrade pre-install.
2013-03-05 18:06:38, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed, not taking backup.
2013-03-05 18:06:39, Information           Setup  Executing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe with commandline -iru.
2013-03-05 18:06:39, Information           Setup  Return code from aspnet_regiis.exe is 0
2013-03-05 18:06:39, Information           Setup  Windows features successfully enabled.
2013-03-05 18:06:39, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05 18-06-39).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-03-05 18-06-39).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000643
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Error                 Setup  
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Error                 Setup  
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Core.SetupException: AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.GenerateAndThrowSetupException(Int32 exitCode, LogEventSource logEventSource)
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.Invoke(LogEventSource logEventSource, InstallMode installMode, String packageIdentity, List`1 updateList, List`1 customArguments)
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.InstallSelectedFeatures()
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.Install()
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Client.ProgressPage.StartAction()
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  === Summary of Actions ===
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Required Windows components   :  Completed Successfully
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  IIS Management Console            :  Completed Successfully
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server  :  Failed
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Hosting Services          :  Failed
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Cache Client          :  Failed
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Hosting Administration            :  Failed
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update  :  Skipped
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update          :  Skipped
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  
2013-03-05 18:07:19, Information           Setup  ===== Logging stopped: 2013-03-05 18:07:19+05:30 =====
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I tried to search every thing but it is not helping me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I search on google and found the solution of this. When I was trying to install the AppFabric before that i have installed SQL Server. Therefore in the `Environment Variable` a variable with the name `PSModulePath` was having SQL Server path inside it.

So I just remove that path and try to install `AppFabric` again and the problem was solved.

It is now installed.

Comment: Finally! an aanswer to my days old dilemma.

Answer (score 6):

This error happend because you've deleted the installtion folder. On disk C that folder name is GUID key in this form c:/75f74225aca163c57a7737aa59a4. You have to rerun WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.msi and before pressing next on the first screen, see the installation path and copy the temporal folder that contain the missing files that has been generated the error code : 1603.

You can see the line before throw the error in you log file

> **Process.Start:** C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe **/quiet** /norestart /i
>   "c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi"
>   ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05
>   18-06-39).log"
>   LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-03-05
>   18-06-39).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server" LANGID=en-US

Then remove the words `Process.Start`: and `/quiet` and execute the command as administrator in MSDOS

> C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /norestart /i
>   "c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi"
>   ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05
>   18-06-39).log"
>   LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-03-05
>   18-06-39).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server" LANGID=en-US

The installer will be go to the step before the error and then ask for the missing folder, select the path of the folder that you copied to C: indicated in the first step up.

Comment: I'll admit I don't really understand why - but this worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, the PSModulePath had the SQL Server 2012 path since I had already installed it, but the path had a trailing double quote ("), which broke any scripts that used the PSModulePath variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the error trace above, it says:-

```
V1.0 is not installed
```

It looks like you are installing an *upgrade* package. So, shouldn't you install 1.0 first *then* 1.1?

Comment: No I directly download AppFabric from this Link [link]http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27115 and installed it.

Comment: Did you install the pre-requisites in the right order and follow the instructions to the letter?

Comment: Yes I installed the pre-requisites from the SharePoint-2013's dvd but in this os(Windows Server 2012) it is not allowing me to install.

Comment: Did you see anything in the appfabric installation log? `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05 18-06-39).log`? It's mentioned in the trace above. It might have more detail on why the msi exploded